# How does a geolocator work?

Tags: android, gps

I need to develop an Android app which is basically a geolocator, allowing people to reach each other via Google maps. All being said, I don't know how do I accomplish such thing since I don't know how it does work and if I need a server or database on the way. I'd be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this topic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question, as it stands, is way too broad for our format. My advice is to do the following: 1. Make sure you've got [the basics](https://developer.android.com/guide/) down 2. Break down your project into (much) smaller tasks 3. Start coding 4. Come back to ask your questions on specific programming issues following [the best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and after searching for potential duplicates. Best of luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you will need Android application and Server through which Android clients will communicate.

**Android Application**

- will be getting data of other Android devices from server and then showing those data on the screen
- will be periodically sending own location to the server

**Server**

- is responsible for storing geolocation of Android clients, data can be stored in some database or memory of the server, depends on the use case, how long you need to have those data, how important they are, etc.
- is responsible for sending stored geolocation data to Android clients
- you have various options, you can write your own server in whatever technology you wish - it can be PHP server, NodeJS server, Java server... or you will use some *[serverless](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html)* solution. Check for example
  https://firebase.google.com
- has to be hosted somewhere, you have many options:
  there are "traditional" hosting providers, where you are usually limited by technologies you can use, for example you can just use PHP or you will use products from [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/).. there is more, Microsoft has Microsoft Azure or Redhat has Openshift.. There are differences in prices, services, etc., it is up to you to look and decide what is the best for you.

I for sure missed lot of things. It is not in my power to describe every possible corner case because the question is too broad but rather provide you with higher overview of the problem and possibly point you where to go next. I suggest to you to read more about problematic and then get back with more specific issues to solve.